# Hosting Angular app on Vercel with dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, package.json, vercel

I get the following error when trying to host my Angular application on Vercel:

> Error: src/app/spotify.service.ts:25:32 - error TS2339: Property 'spotifyApiKey' does not exist on type '{ production: boolean; }'.

This makes sense since the property `spotifyApiKey` is set by a JavaScript script that is called in `package.json`. So my question is how do I tell Vercel to first run the commands in the `package.json` file?

Comment: You need to have the same structure (type) in all of your `environment.ts` files. Take a look at https://angular.io/guide/build.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This makes sense since the property spotifyApiKey is set by a JavaScript script that is called in package.json.

Okay, but you haven't properly typed it. The type should be:

```js
{ production: boolean, spotifyApiKey: string }
```

Yes the key may be inserted later, but you need to clarify that the property exists.

It's also possible you need to change some other code but since you haven't posted at least the service we can't help you further.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It resolved my problem. However, I do not understand yet. Basically, in the service I import the `spotifyApiKey` from an external script (environment is the class in that script), this is indeed a string. Then I typed `const apiKey = environment.spotifyApiKey;` in the service and got the error above. When I change this to `const apiKey: string = environment.spotifyApiKey;` everything is just fine. I know this is TypeScript, but I have the feeling that sometimes the types are really important, like in this situation and other times it does not seem to matter.

Comment: @Larry little hard to explain. Basically you're using Typescript in a strictly typed environment. In certain cases, like async calls or in this case getting the values of an environment file, it doesn't know what to expect. Wether you define a type or not the program would still work, but there are checks built in to give you an error and terminate the build. They're arbitrary errors, not actual errors. It wants you to specify what you're working with for the sake of code quality (most of the time).

Comment: That is quite clear, thank you. I will educate myself some more about these type checks. I will edit my question just to remove the 'sneaked-in' question about renewing the API token (I still have problems with this but this is not the place).